# can we sort dictionary using values?

Tags: python-3.x

we have a string with duplicate char like "aaabbddebe" and we have to find the frequency of char in string. I used a counter function to do this but the next condition is found top 3 max frequency and we have to do sort() dictionary in desc order how can I do it?

```
from collections  import Counter
import operator
import collections

strn=input()
dct=Counter(strn)
a=dct.sort()
print(a)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                              
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>                                                                                                           
    a=dct.sort()                                                                                                                                
AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: Maybe try this link: https://www.includehelp.com/python/counting-the-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string-using-string-count.aspx Otherwise, try `sorted(dct)`. I have not tested it right now, but maybe that would work.

Comment: See the `Counter` documentation, there's a function that does what you want: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort a dictionary because it is inheritedly orderless so you need a ordered type to represent sorted values.

With lambda expression:

```
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
```

After that, if you want a dictionary you can do:

```
import collections

sorted_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `sort` on anything; `Counter` already has a method [`most_common(n)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) which will return what you want:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter('aaabbccdddddeeeee')
top3 = c.most_common(3)
print(top3)
# [('e', 5), ('d', 5), ('a', 3)]
```

Or if you just want the letters:

```
top3letters = [letter for letter, freq in c.most_common(3)]
print(top3letters)
# ['e', 'd', 'a']
```

Answer (score -1):

I have an alternate method, we can use the concept of ASCII code.Save the string in a array then convert the string into ascii code and sort them using sort() function.
Then get the vales back using ASCII code.

```
def ASCII(s):
x = 0
for i in xrange(len(s)):
    x += ord(s[i])*2**(8 * (len(s) - i - 1))
return x
```

to change ASCII value back to string u can use

```
bytes(list).decode()
```

where list is list of ascii codes.